# How to use socket io connect?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

Throws `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: More info: using node.js. Installed socket.io with `npm install socket.io`

Using `node test.js` to run.

Comment: Did u load '/socket.io/socket.io.js'

Comment: How? I thought require does that.

Comment: Try this code ... https://gist.github.com/1b17fd2a7b324cb3411a it is a simple test for nodeJS, using express and socket.io ... You can investigate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

var socket = io.connect('your host');

This is a part of your javascript code declared in your js tag in index.html file. Mean this is code runed on client machine.

see carefully on http://socket.io/#how-to-use